# Apache RewriteCond (subdomain)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to redirect request for a subdomain to main domain.
ie: `xxx.domain.com/blah/xyz` --> `domain.com/blah/xyz`

My rewriteconds work fine for `xxx.domain.com` but for anything like `xxx.domain.com/123/xyz` *400 Bad Request* is all I get…

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What rule are you using right now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule should look like :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L]
```